# Python Pandas converts Datetime in DataFrame to Unix Time in JSON format with too many Zeros

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

When a Pandas dataframe with property `timestamp` being `2013-11-29 19:51:00` is converted to JSON, `timestamp` becomes `1385754660000000000`.

```
print df['timestamp']
print json.loads(row.to_json())
```

**Question:** Why are there so many zeros, shouldn't the result be `1385754660`?

Answer (score 3):

docs are here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#writing-json

in 0.12 you can set date_format='iso' to get a regular date format; epoch defaults to nanoseconds (and is the default)

in 0.13 (release candidate is imminent), you can specify date_unit='ms' (and is the default). this writes epoch units in milliseconds (which is typically what json has)

in both 0.12 and 0.13 read_json will correctly read what is written by to_json
there are quite a few options in how to write the format

various 3rd party json modules may or may not read json correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you want less zeros divide it by 1000000000.